# related entities, nested partial views and viewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, viewmodel

I asked this question in a less clear way yesterday and didn't get any good feedback, so I'm trying again...

I have an entity with related entities that can be created, updated and deleted on one page.

In cases where a related entity is composed of multiple members, so lets say stores that have multiple products, I use partial views.

So the url is say stores.com/store/edit/44

My edit action grabs the store entity with id of 44, then finds products with store id of 44...

**edit to add controller details**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    store store = db.storess.Find(id);
    IList<product> product = db.products.Where(t => t.storeid == store.storeid).ToList();

    var viewModel = new vwstore();
    viewModel.store = store;
    viewModel.products = product;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**end edit**

and puts that in a view model...

```
public store store { get; set; }
public IList<product> products { get; set; }
```

In my view, I strongly type with

```
@model myproject.viewModel.vwstores
```

I display the store details and run a for loop to display each product like this.

```
@for (var p = 0; p < Model.store.products.Count(); c++)
{
    @Html.Partial("_product", Model.product[c]);
}
```

notice I'm passing on the specific product model to the partial view.

In my partial view, I strong type with the root entity type, not the view model like I did above, because that's what I need and that's what I've passed to the partial...

```
@model myProjectModel.product
```

and now I can display the details of the given product.

So now here is my problem. What if product has its own related data, such as categories?

---

Problems

1. I filled public IList products { get; set; } by knowing the store id. I don't know the product ids, so how can I fill a categories list?
2. My expectation was that I would nest a category partial within the product partial, but passing the model is an issue. I need to pass a viewmodel with the product and a list of categories, but with the product partial, only the root entity is available.
3. I can't pass a view model like this...
   @Html.Partial("_categories", myviewmodel.categories[c]);
   it won't compile. Is this what viewdatadictionary is for?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your controller, how are you populating the properties of your view model? Have you tried using '.Include("Category") in your lamda expression query? Have your products got a CategoryId property and a Category navigation property? TWe need to see the controller, and your product entity to help you.

Comment: I've added controller details above. Each category has a product id with a nav property.

Comment: Your Products should have a category Id with a navigation property.. Here's an article about navigation properties and EF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: I don't understand that. Category is a child of product. A product has a collection of categories. It can't have a single category id.

Comment: Well that's up to you, however your data structure is. But if it was me I would have it the other way around, so I can have queries like get all products with category id of x. In my mind a Category has a collection Of Products, not the other way around. If you want to have one product in multiple categories then use a ProductCategory mapping table with Id, ProductId, and CategoryId, this will give you the many to many relationship you need, you can then use joins etc. and query in your domain model to populate category property in the product model. There are so many ways to answer question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RenderAction which calls an action method to render a view. Using this you can populate your view model.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Categories", "Controller", new { productId = product.Id }); }
```

Then your view Model

```
public Product product {get;set;}
public IList<Category> Categories {get;set;}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Categories(int productId)
{
   // populate view model based on  product Id
   return PartialView("_Categories", viewmodel);

}
```

EDIT:

Or just place the Categories in your product Model

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}

public class Category
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

This will allow you to loop through the product categories:

```
@foreach (var category in prodocut.Categories)
{
    <td>@category.Name</td>
}
```

Comment: I haven't used routevalues before - the 3rd param in render partial. Should I be passing the product id here?

Comment: I see. Yes you should. I edited my answer, check it.

Comment: This seems to be the right track. Thanks for your help and congrats on getting to 1000!

Answer (score 0):

See comment below main question

If you have your models set up correctly and you are using Include you can display a products related data through the navigation property by simpley writing p.Category.Name if you want the the Category name of the product

```
public Product
{
   public string Name {get;set;};
   [ForiegnKey("Category")]
   public CategoryId {get;set;};

   public Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

Lamda;

```
db.Products.Where(x => x.ShopId == shopId).Include("Category").ToList();
```

Or however you are doing data access.

You can then access the category data with

```
p.Category.Name
```

Comment: Category would need to be a list. Further, I need to loop through the list of categories and render a partial for each one related to the given product. Does that make sense? I probably wasn't clear about that in the original question.

Comment: I'm having to render a partial because I want to be able to create/edit each category on the same page with everything else, so I have to pass in the model for each one.

Comment: I don't know why you are rendering all these partials. You need to rethink your view models. You don't need to pass in the model for each one. Just the Id. You can pass back the Id to the method to get the record you want to work with, so once the categoryId is in the view you can store it somewhere and pass it back, if it was part of the product model you're sorted. Don't feel too constrained by convention here, you don't have to pass all these models about, that's the point of view models.